# Transitive action of $H^2(M;\Bbb Z)$ on $Spin^c$ structures over $M$

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-topology, principal-bundles, spin-geometry

I’ve a problem understanding why the action of the second cohomology group (integer coefficients) of an oriented smooth manifold $M$ is free and transitive on the set of $Spin^c$. I’m following [these notes on the nLab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/files/StableComplexSpinC.pdf) (Prop D.43) but they dont prove that the action is transitive.

For every two $Spin^c$-structure on $M$, say $P,P’$ the author constructs a chern class $\delta$ (Distinguishing chern class) and then claim that $$P’\cong P\times_{K} U(\Bbb L_{\delta})$$ where $K=\ker \pi\colon Spin^c(n)\to SO(n)$ and $U(\Bbb L_{\delta})$ is the $S^1$-bundle over $M$ associated to the chern class $\delta$.

how can I start building a map between $P’$ and $P\times_{K} U(\Bbb L_{\delta})$ for example?

I'm aware that this question is somehow technical, but i can’t find any resource spelling out the details of transitiveness and freenes of such action.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You consider the fiber sequence $\Bbb{CP}^\infty \to B\text{Spin}^c(n) \to BSO(n).$ Things are easiest if you choose a model of this fibration in which $\Bbb{CP}^\infty$ is a group, and this is a principal $G$-bundle.

---

A brief point on principal bundles: given a principal $G$-bundle $P \to B$, there is an associated bundle of groups, $\text{Aut}(P)$; there is an isomorphism of groups $\text{Aut}(P)_x \cong G$ (an automorphism of the $G$-set $P_x$ is given by right-multiplication by some element of $G$). This bundle is not necessarily trivial, but if $P$ had transition functions $\rho_{\alpha \beta}: U_{\alpha \beta} \to G$ acting on elements of $G$ by left-multiplication, then the transition functions for $\text{Aut}(P)$ act on elements by conjugation by $\rho_{\alpha \beta}$ instead of left multiplication. In particular, if $G$ is abelian, this bundle is trivial, and sections of $\text{Aut}(P)$ are just maps $B \to G$.

Now, given two sections $\sigma_1$ and $\sigma_2$ of $P$, there is an automorphism $g$ of $P$ determined by sending $\sigma_1(x)g(x) = \sigma_2(x)$. Because both $\sigma_1$ and $\sigma_2$ are continuous sections, as is the inversion operation in $G$, so too is $g: B \to \text{Aut}(P)$ continuous. We see that $\Gamma(P)$ is acted on simply transitively by $\Gamma(\text{Aut}(P))$ - provided $\Gamma(P)$ is nonempty. When $G$ is abelian, $\Gamma(\text{Aut}(P)) = \text{Map}(M, G)$, as above.

---

Suppose you have an oriented vector bundle $E$ (coded by a map $f: X \to BSO(n)$), $\text{spin}^c$ structures on $E$ are the same thing as lifts to $\tilde f: X \to B\text{Spin}^c(n)$. This is the same as the space of sections of a principal $\Bbb{CP}^\infty$-bundle written $\text{Spin}^c(E)$, the bundle whose fiber above $x$ is the space of $\text{spin}^c$ structures on $E_x$ (this is the pullback to $X$ of the fiber sequence in the first line of this answer). What was written above is that picking an element of $\Gamma(\text{Spin}^c(E))$ gives a canonical bijection with $\text{Map}(X, \Bbb{CP}^\infty)$. (Of course, this is assuming there exists a $\text{spin}^c$ structure on $E$!)

Passing to homotopy classes, we see that the space of $\text{spin}^c$ structures on $E$ up to isomorphism is acted on simply transitively by $[X, \Bbb{CP}^\infty] = [X, K(\Bbb Z,2)] = H^2(X;\Bbb Z)$, assuming there was a $\text{spin}^c$ structure to begin with.

Another argument (essentially the same as this) runs through obstruction theory, which determines whether or not lifts exist and how many they are; the point being that $H^n(X;\pi_n F)$ is zero only for $n = 2$, where we get $H^2(X;\Bbb Z)$. The *existence* of a lift is determined by a class in $H^3(X;\Bbb Z)$, which turns out to be $\beta w_2(E)$, where $\beta$ is the Bockstein map.

Comment: To be clear, this assumes the existence of a lift in the first place: you can't act on the empty space.

Comment: I guess my problem was "Two sections of a principal bundle differ by multiplication by a map to $G$" I didn't know this result

Comment: @LuigiM I should edit my answer: that is not true as phrased. That is true here because $G$ is abelian (many arguments; it is $BG$ for $G$ a commutative group, you can explicitly write $\Bbb{CP}^\infty$ as the projectivization of the field $\Bbb C(x)$, and it inherits a group structure from that...). In general you differ by a section of $\text{Aut}(P)$.

Comment: I have edited and rephrased the answer in more bundle-theoretic language.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's an impressive answer. I'll meditate on that a little bit before accepting it:)