Torsion Chern class
Let $(Y, \lambda)$ be a closed, contact 3-manifold, and $\xi = \ker(\lambda)$ be the associated two-plane field. In Theorem 7.6 (Page 27) of this note, the author claims that there always exists $\Gamma \in H_1(Y; \mathbb{Z})$ such that $c_1(\xi) + 2PD(\Gamma) \in H^2(Y; \mathbb{Z})$ is torsion. I wonder why that is the case?
Indeed, it suffices to find a complex line bundle $E$ such that $c_1(\xi \otimes E \otimes E) = c_1(\xi) + 2c_1(E)$ is torsion, since then we can take $\Gamma = PD(c_1(E))$ (or the homology class of the zero locus of a generic section of $E$). However, I fail to see why such an $E$ must exist. Does it have something to do with $TY$ being trivial (as mentioned earlier in the note)?

I can answer the question assuming what is written on page 28 of your note.

Two spin-c structures $(\mathbb{S}, \rho)$ and $\left(\mathbb{S}^{\prime}, \rho^{\prime}\right)$ are isomorphic if there is a Hermitian vector bundle isomorphism $\phi: \mathbb{S} \to \mathbb{S}^{\prime}$ such that $\rho^{\prime}(v) \circ \phi=\phi \circ \rho(v)$ for every tangent vector $v$. Let $\operatorname{Spin}^c(Y)$ denote the set of isomorphism classes of spin-c structures on $Y$. This does not depend on the choice of Riemannian metric on $Y$. There is an action of $H^2(Y ; \mathbb{Z})$ on $\operatorname{Spin}^c(Y)$ defined as follows: Given $\alpha \in H^2(Y ; \mathbb{Z})$, let $L_\alpha$ denote the complex line bundle on $Y$ with $c_1\left(L_\alpha\right)=\alpha$, assign it a Hermitian metric, and define
$$
\alpha \cdot(\mathbb{S}, \rho):=\left(\mathbb{S} \otimes L_\alpha, \rho \otimes 1\right) .
$$
It turns out that this action is free and transitive (emphasis mine), so that $\operatorname{Spin}^c(Y)$ is an affine space over $H^2(Y ; \mathbb{Z})$.

Now in definition 8.1 of your note, we can take $\mathbb{S}^{\prime}$ to be $\underline{\mathbb{C}^2}$ as we have a global orthonormal frame on $TY$. Notice that $c_1(\mathbb{S}^{\prime})=0$ as it is a trivial bundle.
On page 28, he defines the spin-c structure that has an underlining hermitian vector bundle $\mathbb{S}:=\underline{\mathbb{C}} \oplus \xi$. So, exists a line bundle $L$ such that
$$\underline{\mathbb{C}^2}\cong\underline{\mathbb{C}}\otimes L \oplus \xi\otimes L.$$
We have $0=c_1(\xi)+2c_1(L)$ by the Whitney sum formula. In particular $c_1(\xi)+2c_1(L)$ is torsion.
This does not answer the question, but it reduces it to understanding why the action of $H^2(Y,\mathbb{Z})$ on $\operatorname{Spin}^c(Y)$ is transitive.

Maybe this will help, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2855874/transitive-action-of-h2m-bbb-z-on-spinc-structures-over-m
